# MathUtilities C# Exception Handling

Tags: c#, math, testing, visual-studio-2012

I need to make a program that tests if all the puncions are correct.
So far I had no trouble but I don't know how to handle an exception.
There is a limit that need to throw an exception if the n exceeds 9. Is there a trick to run this class on visual 2012? In college it worked fine at visual 2010 but at home on 2012 it wont run.

Calling the test

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void Test_Factorial10()
 {
     int result = this.Factorial(-3); 
     Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
 }
```

Function :

```
public int Factorial(int n)
{
    if (n > 9)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("max value is 9", "n");
    }

    else if (n == 1 || n == 0) //
        return 1;

    else
        return n * Factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: When you say it won't run, what happens?

Comment: Exceptions are handled by try catch block. Plus if you want to test exception you can use  ExpectedExceptionAttribute

Comment: As a note, it's good practice to give your tests descriptive names. For example, you might consider renaming `Test_Factorial10` to `Test_Factorial_whenNIsNegative_throwsException` or something like that.

Comment: what will be returnet id i tried Assert.Fail() ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio are you running at home (Express, Pro ...), does it support Unit Testing?

There is nothing in your `Factorial` function that is unsupported or behaves differently in any version of Visual Studio or with any release of the .Net Framework.

I believe that support for unit testing is limited in to Windows Store Apps in Express editions of Visual Studio.

---

If you want to write a faster factorial function, consider this.

```
long Factorial(int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            return 1;

        case 2:
            return 2;

        case 3:
            return 6;

        case 4:
            return 24;

        case 5:
            return 120;

        case 6:
            return 720;

        case 7:
            return 5040;

        case 8:
            return 40320;

        case 9:
            return 362880;

        case 10:
            return 3628800;

        case 11:
            return 39916800;

        case 12:
            return 479001600;

        case 13:
            return 6227020800;

        case 14:
            return 87178291200;

        case 15:
            return 1307674368000;

        case 16:
            return 20922789888000;

        case 17:
            return 355687428096000;

        case 18:
            return 6402373705728000;

        case 19:
            return 121645100408832000;

        case 20:
            return 2432902008176640000;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n");
    }
}
```

Comment: it is express. It looks like it should work. And sadlly i dont have a choice in the matematical function. It has to be that way. Elese i would no limi it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to fix your `Factorial` function to have a base case that handles negative numbers:

```
if(n < 0)
{
    // return, or throw an exception.
}
```

Your `Factorial(-3)` call will recurse here:

```
else
    return n * Factorial(n - 1);
```

Which will either loop forever in an unchecked context, or throw an `OverflowException` in a checked context, depending on your compiler options (see comments on this question).

You're likely in an unchecked context, causing an infinite loop; your test would never pass because `Factorial` never finishes.

Jodrell confirmed that `OverflowException` is not thrown by default for an `int`. However, he also confirmed that `StackException` is thrown when `Factorial` finally recurses too far down.

Comment: I'd expect an `OverflowException` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx pretty quickly.

Comment: @Jodrell Wow. It's time I went to bed, this just confirmed it for me. Will edit, upvoted.

Comment: Actually @Jodrell, I took a closer look. From [MSDN: C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx): `When integer overflow occurs, what happens depends on the execution context, which can be checked or unchecked. In a checked context, an OverflowException is thrown. In an unchecked context, the most significant bits of the result are discarded and execution continues.`. Checked vs. unchecked is [compiler-option-dependent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx).

Comment: you are correct, I've been testing the same, if unchecked, which is the default, you get a little gibberish followed by a lot of zeros. However, since this is recursive I'd expect a `StackOverflow` at some point.

Comment: I can confirm that a `StackOverflow` exception results from a value of -3, unless `checked` is enabled then an`Overflow` exception results.

Comment: @Jodrell Upvoted, thanks for extra effort there, applying edit.

Answer (score 0):

if you write ***rezultatom*** word in code it not work, change it to //rezultatom

```
[TestMethod]
 public void Test_Factorial10()
 {
     int result = this.Factorial(-3); 
     Assert.AreEqual(false, result);//rezultatom
 }
```

Comment: I edited that out, assuming it was a typo. @Shawn correct me if I was wrong!

Comment: Yes it was a typo. To ve more precies a bad translation.